# nested complicated ACL in laravel

Tags: laravel, payment, acl, roles

I'm using spatie/laravel-permission as  ACL system in my project. it's good.
I'm adding payment/accounting/invoice to my project and in this level there is another ACL needed on users works.

for example user A have a feature F1 as our service. until 1 month he/she can use all sections in F1. after that some features in  F1 limited until new invoice payed with user.

so in my controller an Edit method I use authorizeForUser just in user ACL level. now I should add another ACL in F model like authorizeForF(F1->id)?!
and another problem is that this is very complicated and if I forgot to add this, I missed some money!!

Comment: Are you working with permissions or just straight up roles? And can you show us the code?

Comment: both or them. for administrator permission and for other models roles

Comment: Its better to work with permissions and assign permissions to the specific models or roles. In that case you can easily remove permissions untill the user pays the invoice.

Comment: I have an idea. in the route middleware define a  situation for each uri passed that checked for any paymet plan, and if there is and user don't have enough account redirect to sell page and if have the redirect to specific uri. it's better in my mind because of not need to remember every where in code and add new acl to it. also one of my question was that how can I avoid several acl (for each model in several situation: payment,new feature, etc.) repeated in each method of each controller needed.

Comment: I would just check it on login, if the user sign on to your platform you check if the user has outstanding payments. If that is the case you limited the functions available to the user

Answer (score 0):

I have a solution:

seed in a table save all Uri,methods (with `foreach` on `Route::getRoutes()`) as a unic row and assign a score for each of them (default 0). in a `route middllware`, analyze every request uri and compare it with score.(for example uri is /profile/advaence and administrator assign score 2 for that)

if the uri have more than zero score,  user's accountant will checked to continue or   redirect to payment if needed.

this give the administrator of website abbility to assign each uri score and developer has no Responsibility about that.

just I'm worry about uri. because administrors usually don't undrestand them easyly. so, I need another seed for some uri to explain as title.

is it good?

Comment: this sounds overly complicated.  use the package to your advantage.  in the login controller, run whatever checks and remove permission(s) as necessary.  then redirect to the user dashboard, which should only display functions as the user has permission.

Comment: I choose this way because there is no need to check every method.  so when new developers add new method, explain  administrator of website and he/she decide to assign any score to it's uri or not.